# Select time in date time picker salesforce

Tags: visualforce, datetime

I am using a date time field in my visual force page..

Our client wants the time to be selectable instead of typing the time. Is it possible to select the time also like date?

[image]

Comment: See if this post helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738538/salesforce-date-time-value-with-optional-time-portion